# How to append the project path across all source files in python(in most efficient way)?

Tags: python

I have a directory structure for my project as

```
<some_path>/code/project/
                        /conf
                        /data
                        /src/
                            a/x.py
                            b/
                             c/y.py
                            ...
```

- each of x.py, y.py can run in isolation, so has to append the project path in its own script as

> sys.path.append('~/code/project')

- This becomes unmanageable when your code needs to run on multiple machines on cluster and I end up changing the paths manually :(
- Its a bad design and I want to learn what is the best way to append the project
- what is the best way to append the project path in this case so that

  - I dont write  `sys.path.append` in each of the `.py file`
  - I can define a master configuration that runs every time a `.py file` runs

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the path to your project to the [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable.

See the documentation on the [Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for how exactly this is used.

Comment: This can also be accomplished by creating a sitecustomize.py or usercustomize.py in the site-packages directory of your Python installation, and using the methods described in the [site](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#module-site) module to modify `sys.path`, however PYTHONPATH is probably preferable.

Comment: That was it. This helped me a lot